# How to remove or color line/grid in polar chart area using Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I am currently in a berlin start up hustleing to get our website up and running and I get by with HTML AND CSS but a big noob when it comes down to Jquery. Anyway I came across Chart.js and would love to visualize our company success by means of a polar area chart. Yet I want to remove the legend and the grey grid/lines in the background.

```js
const CHART = document.getElementById("lineChart");
console.log(CHART);
let lineChart = new Chart(CHART,{ 
type:'polarArea',
data:{
    labels: ["Car", "Plane", "Train", "Cycle", "Walk", Ship", "Spaceship"],
     datasets: [{
        data: [
            11,
            16,
            7,
            3,
            14
        ],
        backgroundColor: [
            "#FF6384",
            "#4BC0C0",
            "#FFCE56",
            "#E7E9ED",
            "#36A2EB"
        ],
        label: 'My dataset' // for legend
    }],
    labels: [
        "Car",
        "Ship",
        "Plane",
        "Spaceship",
        "Cycle"
    ]
}
});
```

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
}
.chart{
 width: 600px;
 height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testo.css"/>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<div class="chart">
<canvas id="lineChart" width="600" height="600"></canvas></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=script.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont know how to get the options going to get rid off the background grids/numbers. Does anyone know the command to remove the grids in the background?

Would appreciate your help and probs name my 2nd born after you :)

Love from Berlin,

A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple toggle the display of `legend` and also the `scale`, on Graph.js you can pass a options element.

```
options: {
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  scale: {
    display: false
  }
}
```

Check the updated snippet below:

```js
const CHART = document.getElementById("lineChart");
console.log(CHART);
let lineChart = new Chart(CHART,{ 
type:'polarArea',
data:{
    labels: ["Car", "Plane", "Train", "Cycle", "Walk", "Ship", "Spaceship"],
     datasets: [{
        data: [
            11,
            16,
            7,
            3,
            14
        ],
        backgroundColor: [
            "#FF6384",
            "#4BC0C0",
            "#FFCE56",
            "#E7E9ED",
            "#36A2EB"
        ],
        label: 'My dataset' // for legend
    }],
    labels: [
        "Car",
        "Ship",
        "Plane",
        "Spaceship",
        "Cycle"
    ]
},
options: {
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  scale: {
    display: false
  }
}
    
});
```

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
}
.chart{
 width: 600px;
 height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testo.css"/>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<div class="chart">
<canvas id="lineChart" width="600" height="600"></canvas></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=script.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, thank you so much!!! It worked.. You are a true js ninja x Thanks again!

Comment: @Killedbygluten glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just forgot the "

```js
const CHART = document.getElementById("lineChart");
console.log(CHART);
let lineChart = new Chart(CHART,{ 
type:'polarArea',
data:{
    labels: ["Car", "Plane", "Train", "Cycle", "Walk", "Ship", "Spaceship"],
     datasets: [{
        data: [
            11,
            16,
            7,
            3,
            14
        ],
        backgroundColor: [
            "#FF6384",
            "#4BC0C0",
            "#FFCE56",
            "#E7E9ED",
            "#36A2EB"
        ],
        label: 'My dataset' // for legend
    }],
    labels: [
        "Car",
        "Ship",
        "Plane",
        "Spaceship",
        "Cycle"
    ]
}
});
```

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
}
.chart{
 width: 600px;
 height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testo.css"/>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<div class="chart">
<canvas id="lineChart" width="600" height="600"></canvas></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=script.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cheers Fire, your code actually recentred the graph which is another issue I've had and was willing to live with ..hehe. However, the actual grey grids in the background are still there. Thanks anyway though x